# Subtracting "variable[#]" with two digits in python?

Tags: python, time, subtraction

I'm building a script in python to calculate the amount of time in between hours entered by a user
Lets say for example I did the following

```
time = input("Enter times:")
```

and the user entered 3,11 to show that the start time was three, and the end time was 11.
Therefore, time would equal 3,11.
I want to be able to subtract this to show that there is an 8 hour difference

I tried using

```
timesub= (int(time[3])-int(time[1]))
```

but it gives me -2 because time[3] is equal to 1. How do I make it use 11 instead of 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
time_input = raw_input("Enter times:")
time_parts = time.split(',')
time_diff = int(time_parts[1]) - int(time_parts[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` method to split a string and assign the individual values to separate variables:

```
start, end = time.split(',')
timesub = int(end) - int(start)
```

If you want to get extra fancy you could apply the `int` function at the same time:

```
start, end = [int(t) for t in time.split(',')]
# or
start, end = map(int, time.split(','))

timesub = end - start
```